# Display specific data from a collections in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi all I am very new in mongodb and I have some problems when I try to do some find in a collections I hope so someone can help me.

Imagine I have the following collection:

```
{
columns:[
    'Divisa',
    '05/10/2015',
    '02/10/2015',
    '01/10/2015',
    '30/09/2015',
    '29/09/2015',
    '28/09/2015',
    '25/09/2015',
    '24/09/2015',
    ],
data:[
        {
            'Divisa':'USD',
            '05/10/2015':'11236',
            '02/10/2015':'1116',
            '01/10/2015':'11153',
            '30/09/2015':'11203',
            '29/09/2015':'11204',
            '28/09/2015':'1117',
            '25/09/2015':'11151',
            '24/09/2015':'11241'            
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'BGD',
            '05/10/2015':'19558',
            '02/10/2015':'19558',
            '01/10/2015':'19558',
            '30/09/2015':'19558',
            '29/09/2015':'19558',
            '28/09/2015':'19558',
            '25/09/2015':'19558',
            '24/09/2015':'19558'                
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'CYP',
            '05/10/2015':'0',
            '02/10/2015':'0',
            '01/10/2015':'0',
            '30/09/2015':'0',
            '29/09/2015':'0',
            '28/09/2015':'0',
            '25/09/2015':'0',
            '24/09/2015':'0'                
    }               
    ]
}
```

Now I want do some find inside the collections for exmample:

A-I want to bring me all currencies search by date range  05/10/2015 to 01/10/2015 then I need that return something like this:

```
{
columns:[
    'Divisa',
    '05/10/2015',
    '02/10/2015',
    '01/10/2015',       
    ],
data:[
        {
            'Divisa':'USD',
            '05/10/2015':'11236',
            '02/10/2015':'1116',
            '01/10/2015':'11153',               
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'BGD',
            '05/10/2015':'19558',
            '02/10/2015':'19558',
            '01/10/2015':'19558',               
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'CYP',
            '05/10/2015':'0',
            '02/10/2015':'0',
            '01/10/2015':'0',               
    }               
    ]
}
```

I want to know what is the structure of the find that I need to use for have a result similar.

B-Also I need to know how do a find that return all the information related with a currency, for example I want searh all releated with the currency 'USD', I need return something similar to:

```
 columns:[
        'Divisa',
        '05/10/2015',
        '02/10/2015',
        '01/10/2015',
        '30/09/2015',
        '29/09/2015',
        '28/09/2015',
        '25/09/2015',
        '24/09/2015',
        ],
    data:[
            {
                'Divisa':'USD',
                '05/10/2015':'11236',
                '02/10/2015':'1116',
                '01/10/2015':'11153',
                '30/09/2015':'11203',
                '29/09/2015':'11204',
                '28/09/2015':'1117',
                '25/09/2015':'11151',
                '24/09/2015':'11241'            
        }           
        ]
    }
```

I want to know what is the structure of the find that I need to use for have a result similar.

C-And finally I need to know how do a find that return all the information related with a value, for example I want search all the information with value of 0 between 12000, I need return something similar to:

```
{
columns:[
    'Divisa',
    '05/10/2015',
    '02/10/2015',
    '01/10/2015',
    '30/09/2015',
    '29/09/2015',
    '28/09/2015',
    '25/09/2015',
    '24/09/2015',
    ],
data:[
        {
            'Divisa':'USD',
            '05/10/2015':'11236',
            '02/10/2015':'1116',
            '01/10/2015':'11153',
            '30/09/2015':'11203',
            '29/09/2015':'11204',
            '28/09/2015':'1117',
            '25/09/2015':'11151',
            '24/09/2015':'11241'            
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'CYP',
            '05/10/2015':'0',
            '02/10/2015':'0',
            '01/10/2015':'0',
            '30/09/2015':'0',
            '29/09/2015':'0',
            '28/09/2015':'0',
            '25/09/2015':'0',
            '24/09/2015':'0'                
    }               
    ]
}
```

I want to know what is the structure of the find that I need to use for have a result similar.

Comment: You are doing this completely wrong and should never use "data" as the names of keys as you have done here everywhere. MongoDB cannot query "keys" and certainly cannot produce the results you want here in any efficient way for this structure. What do you really need to achieve? As it seems restructuring for your real purpose is what is required here.

Comment: This appears to be exchange data. Could you not simply store the data as {'seriesdate':'24/09/2015','exchange_rate':'11241','currency':'USD'} with one entry a day for each currency? You may also want to store the source currency.

Comment: Data in mongodb should always be stored as key-value and hence using the find query will be so easy and you will get all the result. Also aggregation is the best to get all the result in a single query.