# Display information of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hi all I am very new in mongodb and I have some problems when I try to do some find in a collections I hope so someone can help me.
Imagine I have the following collection:

```
db.fechasCambio.insert(
{
columns:[
    'Divisa',
    '05/10/2015',
    '02/10/2015',
    '01/10/2015',
    '30/09/2015',
    '29/09/2015',
    '28/09/2015',
    '25/09/2015',
    '24/09/2015',
    ],
data:[
        {
            'Divisa':'USD',
            '05/10/2015':'11236',
            '02/10/2015':'1116',
            '01/10/2015':'11153',
            '30/09/2015':'11203',
            '29/09/2015':'11204',
            '28/09/2015':'1117',
            '25/09/2015':'11151',
            '24/09/2015':'11241'            
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'BGD',
            '05/10/2015':'19558',
            '02/10/2015':'19558',
            '01/10/2015':'19558',
            '30/09/2015':'19558',
            '29/09/2015':'19558',
            '28/09/2015':'19558',
            '25/09/2015':'19558',
            '24/09/2015':'19558'                
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'CYP',
            '05/10/2015':'0',
            '02/10/2015':'0',
            '01/10/2015':'0',
            '30/09/2015':'0',
            '29/09/2015':'0',
            '28/09/2015':'0',
            '25/09/2015':'0',
            '24/09/2015':'0'                
    }               
    ]
}
) c
```

Now I want do some find inside the collections for example:

A-I want to bring me all currencies search by date range  05/10/2015 to 01/10/2015 then I need that return something like this:

```
{
columns:[
    'Divisa',
    '05/10/2015',
    '02/10/2015',
    '01/10/2015',       
    ],
data:[
        {
            'Divisa':'USD',
            '05/10/2015':'11236',
            '02/10/2015':'1116',
            '01/10/2015':'11153',               
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'BGD',
            '05/10/2015':'19558',
            '02/10/2015':'19558',
            '01/10/2015':'19558',               
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'CYP',
            '05/10/2015':'0',
            '02/10/2015':'0',
            '01/10/2015':'0',               
    }               
    ]
}
```

I want to know what is the structure of the find that I need to use for have a result similar.

B-Also I need to know how do a find that return all the information related with a currency, for example I want searh all releated with the currency 'USD', I need return something similar to:

```
{
columns:[
    'Divisa',
    '05/10/2015',
    '02/10/2015',
    '01/10/2015',
    '30/09/2015',
    '29/09/2015',
    '28/09/2015',
    '25/09/2015',
    '24/09/2015',
    ],
data:[
        {
            'Divisa':'USD',
            '05/10/2015':'11236',
            '02/10/2015':'1116',
            '01/10/2015':'11153',
            '30/09/2015':'11203',
            '29/09/2015':'11204',
            '28/09/2015':'1117',
            '25/09/2015':'11151',
            '24/09/2015':'11241'            
    }           
    ]
}
```

I want to know what is the structure of the find that I need to use for have a result similar.

C-And finally I need to know how do a find that return all the information related with a value, for example I want search all the information with value of 0 between 12000, I need return something similar to:

```
{
columns:[
    'Divisa',
    '05/10/2015',
    '02/10/2015',
    '01/10/2015',
    '30/09/2015',
    '29/09/2015',
    '28/09/2015',
    '25/09/2015',
    '24/09/2015',
    ],
data:[
        {
            'Divisa':'USD',
            '05/10/2015':'11236',
            '02/10/2015':'1116',
            '01/10/2015':'11153',
            '30/09/2015':'11203',
            '29/09/2015':'11204',
            '28/09/2015':'1117',
            '25/09/2015':'11151',
            '24/09/2015':'11241'            
    },
    {
            'Divisa':'CYP',
            '05/10/2015':'0',
            '02/10/2015':'0',
            '01/10/2015':'0',
            '30/09/2015':'0',
            '29/09/2015':'0',
            '28/09/2015':'0',
            '25/09/2015':'0',
            '24/09/2015':'0'                
    }               
    ]
}
```

I want to know what is the structure of the find that I need to use for have a result similar.

Comment: Duplicate of [Display specific data from a collections in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602866/display-specific-data-from-a-collections-in-mongodb) which is your own question. Please do not add the same question again just because no-one has answered it yet.

Comment: Beside what your are ask, I would like to comment on your schema design. I don't feel it correct. It's look me your are inserting whole data set as one document. It's more natural if you insert the element in your "data" array as separate documents. For your understanding, check this out https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/